# Offset and radial surveys

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Calculate the area of field $CDEFG$, expressing your answer correct to the nearest square metre.
>
> [image]

Can someone help me with the first question in the exercise? This is what I've done so far.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Triangle }CHD &= 0.5 \times 43 \times 20 \\
\text{Triangle }CIG &= 0.5 \times 41 \times 45 \\
\text{Triangle }GIJ &= 0.5 \times 41 \times 105 \\
\text{Triangle }JEF &= 0.5 \times 48 \times 17 \\
\text{Trapezium }DHJE &= \text{??}
\end{align}$$

The answer is $9055\,\mathrm m^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the graphic and try to figure out why if a trapezoid has parallel sides $a$ and $b$ with a height of $h$ that
$$A=h\times\text{ average of the bases}=h\times\frac{a+b}{2}$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the point $D'$ on $JE$ such that $\angle JD'D = 90^\circ$. Then split the trapezoid in the rectangle $JHDD'$ and the triangle $DD'E$. Can you solve it from there?